# How do I access a package protected class in Maven build?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, easymock

Some code returns a package protected type which I am trying to mock. I was doing so using `Class.forName`, but Maven throws an `IllegalAccessError` now.

Here is a sample:

```
Class<?> itemSupportClasss = Class.forName("com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.IteratorSupport");
Iterator<Item> mockIterator = (Iterator<Item>) createMock(itemSupportClasss);
expect(mockIterator.hasNext()).andReturn(false);

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> itemCollection = createMock(ItemCollection.class);
expect(((Iterable<Item>) itemCollection).iterator()).andReturn(mockIterator);

// And so on
```

When `itemCollection.iterator()` is called, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/internal/IteratorSupport
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.ItemCollection$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$14504e4e.iterator(<generated>)
    at com.mycom.MyClass(MyClass.java:77)
    at com.mycom.MyClass(MyClass.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Of course, the root issue is that Dynamo DB returns a package protected class as an iterator, but what can you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem here is that you are trying to mock `ItemCollection` and have it return a real object. The only way you're going to be able to solve this problem, unfortunately, is using PowerMock:

https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Motivation
https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation

All you have to do, when using the [PowerMockRunner](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.1/apidocs/org/powermock/modules/junit4/PowerMockRunner.html), is put the package private class in [`@PrepareForTest`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.1/apidocs/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html) and it should handle it for you. If this is not enough for you let me know in the comments.

Comment: I've dug into it a bit more and it seems that package access is restricted by the Java security policy being used to run the tests. Will PowerMock be able to circumvent this?

Comment: @Max Yes. Read the links